# Calling a remote .NET DLL inside COM+ without the proxy installation

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop, com+

We have a three tier application entirely developed in .NET 4.0 (C#). As the enterprise application server we use COM+ 1.5 (I know it's a little bit legacy...). There are a server part and a client part both developed in C# for .NET 4.0.

The server part exposes services inheriting the ServicedComponent class and returning objects which implement the "Serializable" attribute. The client calls the remote classes via the COM+ exported proxy of the component. We distribute the client app through ClickOnce and we have to install, with Admin privileges, the COM+ generated Proxy onto every client machine. This is the bad point.

So we are trying to evaluate other techniques which allow us to eliminate this proxy installation but it's not so clear how to do this. We'd like to find a low impact way that allow us to use the same COM+ part and including in some way the Proxy into the client side code.

We have tried to use code like this in the client part but still requires the COM registration.

```
Type comObjectType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SumNameSpace.SumClass", "servercomplus", true);
SumInterface comObject = Activator.CreateInstance(comObjectType) as SumInterface;
```

We thought that using in the client part the interface instead the class would have to work, but we have the exception:

```
Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800401F3): Invalid class string (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING))
```

This error should happen if there aren't the correct information about the Interface in the Windows Registry, but we don't know...

Any idea?

thanks a lot

Comment: Have you checked a potential 32/64 bit issue?

Comment: I have tried onto 32 bit Windows VISTA and there is the same error! tnx

Comment: Could you use the registration-free COM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx ?

Comment: It seems it does not work for native assembly COM. It only works for ActiveX COM that has the Isolated property...but I am not sure. If someone has an example for a client developed in .NET that want to use a COM that is developed in .NET code it would be better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no question you need the COM+ proxy installed on all the client machines, and you want to install it with the proxy installation package. The error you're getting is the result of the missing ProgID entry under the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT hive in the registry. This registry entry, among others, is provided by the installation package. This isn't all the the proxy installer provides; I found a pretty good overview [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680546(v=vs.85).aspx).

It sounds like what you are really looking for is to create a custom application manifest for your ClickOnce deployment. This should allow you to bundle the proxy installer as a bootstrap prerequisite into your ClickOnce deployment. However the install will still require administrative permissions; I don't see a way around that (see note below). Here is [a link to a tool](http://www.clickoncemore.net/home.php) that works with ClickOnce manifests that was created by Stackoverflow user [Greg Jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389816/greg-jackman). I don't have any experience with this, but based on Greg's post it looks like it may be helpful to you.

One final note: even if you do find a way to run the installation package as a non-elevated user, you don't want to do that. Running non-elevated will change the way the package interacts with the registry. Short story, it will fail silently.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I remember something about the HKLC registry part that can be "emulated" in the HKCU path of the registry. It is related to REG-free COM modality...look at this URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188708.aspx

But probably I'm mixing different things..I cannot believe Microsoft has not think about COM+ Proxy integration in ClickOnce process. The only one explanation could be that it's legacy and not supported anymore

Comment: Another point is this: why do I need to have in the registry the CLSID when I use only the Interface?

Comment: Because Activator uses COM to instantiate the object, and COM must look in the registry to find the COM server binary for the ProgID SumNameSpace.SumClass (via the ClassID, which is also in the registry)

Comment: Regarding HKCL emulation, you are correct but I'm trying to keep the answer simple(ish). This relates to why you can't properly register the component unless you're running elevated. Using a proxy via registration free COM is a stretch because the proxy has other dependencies.

Comment: Paul do you have a working example for HKCL emulation that I can use?

Comment: I don't think you understand - it's the OS that emulates HKLM. Emulation behavior varies for admins and non-admins. That's one reason why it's impossible to install a COM+ proxy successfully unless you are running as an administrator.

Comment: Sorry probably I wrote not so well what I want. I'd like to have an example of COM-reg free for both tier developed in .NET using COM+ as Remote part.

Comment: If you can get a COM+ proxy working using only registration-free COM, and do it consistently on machines that have no previous install, I will be shocked. COM+ is 15 year old technology and it doesn't surprise me that Microsoft has made no provisions for it in ClickOnce. I can see 2 clear paths forward for you: 1) rewrite your system to eliminate the dependence on COM+ 2) accept the fact that you already have about as good of an installation story as you're going to get. If you succeed in doing the impossible and using reg free COM for this, please post your results; I'll be impressed.

Comment: Thanks Paul. In the case we evaluate to rewrite out system what do you advice to us? WCF?

Comment: At risk of oversimplifying I would say: yes!

Comment: I assume there are a lot of reference for WCF around here, butt migrating from COM+, what kind of serializer do you advice, what kind of approach? Do you have a link to a brief guide to follow? Thanks...but you are gaining my 50 points and I need as much as possible from you :-D

Comment: I can't give you a complete answer in a stackoverflow comment, but if you want to contact me directly my email is in my user profile. Very briefly, I would transform all of the objects that currently derive from ServicedComponent into interfaces with backing implementations. The question then becomes: what are you missing that you used to get from COM+?

Comment: I wrote you in private. Thanks a lot..you got the 50 points :)

Answer (score 1):

Use group policy to distribute the components?

Comment: we use a distribution product to deploy the proxy component, but we'd prefer to include the proxy part into the client application and deploy the whole with ClickOnce

Comment: Ben  I've just seen your score...probably you know the answer, so let's go! :)

Comment: @robob, if you already have a way to distribute the component - just keep using it! That's my advice anyway.

Comment: Ben we want to change it because the deploying timing is very important for us. So we would like to use the ClickOnce deployment power for every client part. I'm sure there is a way to integrate the proxy part in the client part...thanks for you reply. I think I start a Bounty for this question

Comment: If you are able to distribute the DLL using ClickOnce you can probably register it on startup using P/Invoke to call DllRegisterServer.

Comment: I do not want to implement so low level solutions...I'd like to know a more high level solutions. I saw something about COM-reg free to embed CLSID and Typelib informations in the assembly manifest, but all the references I can find are for local and old COM (as the COM created from VB6) while I need a COM-reg free approach with .NET exposed in COM+ (Remote).